# Trying to set date time within ubuntu based docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, timezone, date

Within my docker container I run:

```
root@77defb7a21e5:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie)
Release:    8.9
Codename:   jessie
root@77defb7a21e5:/# date
Tue Aug  7 16:54:14 UTC 2018
root@77defb7a21e5:/# dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

Current default time zone: 'America/Denver'
Local time is now:      Tue Aug  7 16:54:23 UTC 2018.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Aug  7 16:54:23 UTC 2018.
```

What, from within the container, needs to be set to make the local time the true `America/Denver`?

My container was created using:

```
  sudo docker run --name=my_db --network=my_nw -v /opt/mydata:/var/lib/postgresql/mydata -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepassword -d postgres:9.5.9
```

and I got the file  `/etc/timezone`  to have only `America/Denver`. I also re-started the container but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the timezone you want is the same as the host, the best way I found to do this is as follow:

`docker run -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro ......`

Comment: but I am already using -v for the data. Is it possible to use -v several times?

Comment: Yes, you can mount as many volume as you want.